# Dropping data in range buckets

Tags: python

I have two dimentional data stored in a sorted list of tuples, as follows:

```
data = [(0.1,100), (0.13,300), (0.2,10)...
```

The first value in each tuple, the X value, only occurs once for the list of tuples. In other words, there can only be one value for 0.1 etc.

I then have a sorted list of buckets. A bucket is defined as a tuple containing a range and an id, as follows:

```
buckets = [((0,0.14), 2), ((0.135,0.19), 1), ((0.19,0.21), 2), ((0.19,0.24), 3)...
```

A range is with respect to the X axis. So, the id 2 has two buckets above and ids 1 and 3 have only one, respectively. The first bucket for id 2 has a range from 0 to 0.14. Please note that buckets can overlap.

So, I need an algorithm which drops the data into the buckets and then adds up the scores. For the data above, the result would be:

```
1:0
2:410
3:10
```

Notice how each piece of data is caught by a bucket associated with the id 2, hence it gets the score `100+300+10=410`.

How might I write an algorithm to do this?

Comment: Just occurred to me that what you are describing can be implemented as an [Interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Have a read of https://github.com/brentp/quicksect/tree

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
data = [(0.1,100), (0.13,300), (0.2,10)]
buckets = [((0,0.14), 2), ((0.135,0.19), 1), ((0.19,0.21), 2), ((0.19,0.24), 3)]

def foo(tpl): ## determine the buckets a data-tuple is enclosed by list of IDs
    x, s = tpl
    lst = []
    for bucket in buckets:
        rnge, iid = bucket
        if x>rnge[0] and x<rnge[1]: lst.append(iid)
    return lst

data = [[dt, foo(dt)] for dt in data]

scores_dict = {}
for tpl in data:
    score = tpl[0][1]
    for iid in tpl[1]:
        if iid in scores_dict: scores_dict[iid]+=score
        else:                  scores_dict[iid] =score

for key in scores_dict:
    print key,":",scores_dict[key]
```

This snippet results in:

```
2 : 410
3 : 10
```

If any bucket ID is not printed, there is no X value in that bucket or it sums zero.

Answer (score 1):

Turn each bucket definition (label range) into a callable that - given the data tuple - will increment the bucket total. Bucket values are stored in a simple dict. You can easily wrap this concept up in a class if you want to provide a simpler api.

```
def partition(buckets, bucket_definition):
    """Build a callable that increments the appropriate buckets with a value"""

    lower, upper = bucket_definition[0]
    key = bucket_definition[1]

    def _partition(data):
        x, y = data
        # Set a default value for this key
        buckets.setdefault(key, 0)

        if lower <= x <= upper:
            buckets[key] += y

    return _partition


bucket_definitions = [
    ((0, 0.14), 2),
    ((0.135, 0.19), 1),
    ((0.19, 0.21), 2),
    ((0.19, 0.24), 3)
]

data = [(0.1, 100), (0.13, 300), (0.2, 10)]

# Holder for bucket labels and values
buckets = {}

# For each bucket definition (range, label) build a callable
partitioners = [partition(buckets, definition) for definition in bucket_definitions]

# Map each callable to each data tuple provided
for partitioner in partitioners:
    map(partitioner, data)

print(buckets)
```

Comment: You can do `if lower >= x >= upper:` and Python does the right thing.

Comment: @Rob Cowie It should be: if lower <= x <= upper:

Comment: Urgh; I blame late night coding. Cheers @Baz

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired output from your test data:

```
data = [(0.1,100), (0.13,300), (0.2,10)]
buckets = [((0,0.14), 2), ((0.135,0.19), 1), ((0.19,0.21), 2), ((0.19,0.24), 3)]

totals = dict()

for bucket in buckets:
    bucket_id = bucket[1]
    if bucket_id not in totals:
        totals[bucket_id] = 0
    for data_point in data:
        if data_point[0] >= bucket[0][0] and data_point[0] <= bucket[0][1]:
            totals[bucket_id] += data_point[1]

for key in sorted(totals):
    print("{}: {}".format(key, totals[key]))
```

Comment: It is an emphasis that the buckets can overlap with each other. Provided that there are two buckets (with the same ID) overlap, this seams likely to count some data more than once.